# Filter a complex vector in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a mocked data of groups, each group contains users. here is the data I have:

```
(def group-list 
     [{:name "group1"
       :id "group1"
       :members [{:name "Bartek" :id "mem1"}
                 {:name "Quentin"  :id "mem2"}]}
      {:name "group2"
       :id "group2"
       :members [{:name "Bartek_test" :id "mem3"}
                 {:name "Quentin"  :id "mem2"}]}
      {:name "group3"
       :id "group3"
       :members [{:name "Bartek1" :id "mem1"}]}])
```

What I want to do is to create a function which will take user id as a parameter, search in group-list and return the full record. For example, if the id will be `mem2` method should return `{:name "group2" :id "group2" :members [{:name "Bartek_test"  :id "mem3"} {:name "Quentin"  :id "mem2"}]}`

I am a new to clojure so it would be great if anybody gives some idea. Thank you

Comment: `mem2` looks to be in `group1` as well.  Do you want to return both?

Comment: yes would be great

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I solved it with this solution: `(defn get-groups-by-member [member-id]
    (filter (fn [x] (some #(= member-id %) (map #(get % :id) (x :members)))) (get-group-list)) )`

Comment: To solve these kinds of problems and a lot of others with less code I can recommend taking a look at [specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter). This library abstracts navigation through nested data structures. I have no time to look at this now but would be glad to make an example later.

Comment: @fishera your solution is good, you should post it as the answer. As Erwin said, it is worth mentioning Specter as well, although it may be an overkill for a beginner as you.

Comment: it would be nice if you could provide this example using Specter.

Comment: If you've got a working solution, you should formally answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defn get-groups-by-member [member-id]
  (filter (fn [x]
            (some #(= member-id %)
                  (map #(get % :id)
                       (x :members))))
          (get-group-list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using [specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter)'s [`select`](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter/wiki/List-of-Macros#select), [`VAL`](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter/wiki/List-of-Navigators#val) and [`ALL`](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter/wiki/List-of-Navigators#all):

```
(require '[com.rpl.specter :refer [select ALL VAL]])

(defn find-groups [id]
  (map first (select [ALL VAL :members ALL #(= (:id %) id)] group-list)))

(find-groups "mem2")

;; => ({:name "group1", 
;;      :id "group1", 
;;      :members [{:name "Bartek", :id "mem1"} {:name "Quentin", :id "mem2"}]}
;;     {:name "group2", 
;;      :id "group2", 
;;      :members [{:name "Bartek_test", :id "mem3"} {:name "Quentin", :id "mem2"}]})
```

Note that it finds two groups, since "mem1" is part of "group1" and "group2".